# Dynamic Linq select statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq, select, dynamic

I have a statement like this =

```
var result =
    from c in displayedUsers
    select
    new string[]
    {
        c.GetType().GetProperty(columnList[0]).GetValue(c, null).ToString(),
        c.GetType().GetProperty(columnList[1]).GetValue(c, null).ToString(),
        c.GetType().GetProperty(columnList[2]).GetValue(c, null).ToString(),
        c.GetType().GetProperty(columnList[3]).GetValue(c, null).ToString()
    };
```

What I want to know is if it's possible to not have to have a static list length (in this case you can see there are only 4 items)

How would I do this if I had N number of columns in the 'columnList' array?

Something along the lines of =

```
var result =
    from c in displayedUsers
    select
    new string[]
    {
        foreach item in columnList GetValue
        ...
    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: What Type is columnList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var columnList = new []{"cola", "colb"};
var result = from c in displayUsers
             select
             (
                 (
                     from col in Columnlist
                     select c.GetType().GetProperty(col).GetValue(c, null).ToString()
                 ).ToArray();
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

If columnList can be cast or converted to a List then there's the ForEach method that could be used.